# What's the difference between coefficient of variation and intraclass coefficient and when should I use one vs the other?

Tags: intraclass-correlation, coefficient-of-variation

If I am trying to compare variability in a measurement taken multiple times in a single session with the variability in that measurement taken over multiple sessions, should I use icc or cov?

I am really looking for a way to understand what icc provides in a context that isn't about different raters, but I am having trouble understanding.